# Factor and Remainder Theorem

Tags: polynomials

Please help me with this exam style question from the [IGCSE 2020 Specimen Paper](https://www.cambridgeinternational.org/Images/415748-2020-specimen-paper-4.pdf). 
The polynomial
$$p(x)=2x^3 -3x^2 +qx+56$$
has $x-2$ as a factor.
Show that $q=-30$.

Comment: Divide it straightaway.When you get the remainder in terms of q,say aqx+b,equate each coefficient to zero as it is a factor

Comment: I think $q = \color{blue}{-}30$. Just set $p(2) = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

If $x-2$ is a factor, then $p(2)= 2\cdot 2^3 -3 \cdot 2^2 + q\cdot 2 + 56 = 0$.
$$\Rightarrow 2q = -60$$

Answer (score 1):

You want $P(2)=0$

What is $ P(2)$ when $ p(x)=2x^3 -3x^2 +qx+56$?

Let $x=2$ and solve for $q$